# Understanding the term 'Uniqueness' in a definition.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, terminology, definition, proof-explanation

The formal definition of the division theorem states that the quotient and remainder ( $  q, r \in  \mathbb{Z}  $)  are said to be 'unique'.

Does that imply that if there exists quotient and remainder $q', \,r' \in  \mathbb{Z}  \quad then \, \, q=q' \, \,  and \, \,  r'=r$ has to be true?

Answer (score 3):

More precisely, if $a = bq + r = bq'+r'$ where $0 \le r, r' < b$, then $q=q'$ and $r=r'$.